# Exporting Eclipse Executable Projects

Tags: eclipse, build, makefile, eclipse-cdt

This seems to be a common and simple problem but I cannot find a useful answer anywhere. At this stage I'm at my wits end!

Using eclipse with the CDT pluggin I have created an "executable" C++ project containing 10s of source files which auto builds (but does not appear to save a makefile ... it does generate a .cproject xml file however).

My question is very basic: This is one of the 3 main CDT project types - how do I move/export it, as is, to another machine and simply retain the auto build feature? Selecting export just generates a rather useless file with little info.

Comment: Is convert to a C/C++ autotools project what you are looking for? I've never used it before, but it looks promising. It's in New-> Other->C/C++

Comment: Nope, defo not it! Now I've lost auto build completely on my original project :(

Comment: Oh man, sorry! Like I said, I've never used it before. There's an option in the C/C++ Build settings page that says Generate Makefiles automatically. If you can't select it, change the builder to External.

Comment: No worries dude, have already resigned myself to writing a CMake file for this project, I'm just genuinely interested in the above question ... it just shouldn't be that difficult! If anything it should be a pretty standard thing to do!!